# CUB block reduce a custom vector type

Tags: cuda

I am trying to sum a few floats across a thread block using the CUB library in CUDA. I know how to reduce a single float (using a 2D thread block in this case):

```
float sum = globalInput[threadIdx.x + threadIdx.y * blockDim.x];

typedef cub::BlockReduce<float, THREAD_BLOCK_X, cub::BLOCK_REDUCE_RAKING, THREAD_BLOCK_Y> BlockReduce;

// Allocate shared memory for BlockReduce
__shared__ typename BlockReduce::TempStorage temp_storage;
  
// Compute the block-wide sum for thread0
float aggregate = BlockReduce(temp_storage).Sum(sum);
```

Is it possible to generalize this algorithm to work with vector types such as float2, float4, etc.? I suppose I could reduce one float at a time, but that would involve multiple underlying __syncthreads() that wouldn't be necessary in a composite reduction.

Comment: You could use type punning (e.g. via `memcpy` to avoid UB) to transform your `float2` into a array of two floats for which there is an overload of `BlockReduce`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

CUDA doesn't natively provide arithmetic operators for the "built-in" vector types.  So pretty much the only thing needed to extend the [basic example](https://nvlabs.github.io/cub/classcub_1_1_block_reduce.html) for e.g. `float2` is to provide an appropriate reduction operator:

```
$ cat t2259.cu
#include <cub/cub.cuh>
__host__ __device__
float2 operator+(const float2 &a, const float2 &b){return float2{a.x+b.x, a.y+b.y};}

__global__ void ExampleKernel()
{
    // Specialize BlockReduce for a 1D block of 128 threads of type float2
    typedef cub::BlockReduce<float2, 128> BlockReduce;
    // Allocate shared memory for BlockReduce
    __shared__ typename BlockReduce::TempStorage temp_storage;
    // Obtain a segment of consecutive items that are blocked across threads
    float2 thread_data[4];
    thread_data[0].x = 1.0f;
    thread_data[0].y = 2.0f;
    thread_data[1].x = 2.0f;
    thread_data[1].y = 3.0f;
    thread_data[2].x = 1.0f;
    thread_data[2].y = 2.0f;
    thread_data[3].x = 2.0f;
    thread_data[3].y = 3.0f;

    // Compute the block-wide sum for thread0
    float2 aggregate = BlockReduce(temp_storage).Sum(thread_data);
    if (!threadIdx.x) printf("aggregate.x: %f .y: %f\n", aggregate.x, aggregate.y);
}


int main(){

  ExampleKernel<<<1,128>>>();
  cudaDeviceSynchronize();
}
$ nvcc -o t2259 t2259.cu
$ compute-sanitizer ./t2259
========= COMPUTE-SANITIZER
aggregate.x: 768.000000 .y: 1280.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```